# Erro ao cria projeto cordova

Tags: apache-cordova

Como resolver esse erro que está dando no cordova 5.1.1 com node 4.1.1?

```
Creating a new cordova project.
Could not find directory: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-app-hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você instala o Cordova ele armazena em suas pastas de instalação uma versão do HelloWorld do projeto para cada plataforma (uma pro Android, outra pro Windows Phone, IOS e etc.). É por isso que é possível criar os projetos "vazios" quando necessário.

Quando essa mensagem de erro acontece, quer dizer que houve algum problema na instalação do Cordova, ou seja, algum dos projetos HelloWorld não foi instalado corretamente. Pra resolver você tem duas opções:

*1 - Remova tudo relacionado ao Cordova e instale novamente;*

*2 - Baixe do repositório do Cordova as pastas de cada plataforma e instale manualmente nos diretórios que não receberam a instalação correta (eu já fiz isso. Funciona, mas vai dar bastante problema até ficar belezinha).
Diretórios a explorar:*

**O mesmo do Erro:** C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\

**Intalação do Cordova:**
C:\Users\USUARIO.cordova\lib

**PS:** Lembre-se que a instalação correta deve ser feita seguindo os passos de implantação do Windows. Veja mais em: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html